# Rearrange rows in a table to one column (excel / pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to organise data from rows to rearrange themselves in to a singular column. For instance, if there was a table of 4 columns, 4 rows, I would want to rearrange that table in to one singular column of 16 pieces of data, with the first row as the first four pieces of data, followed by the second and so on.

Ideally this is done via some python script using pandas.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with remove `MultiIndex` by [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)).add_prefix('col')
print (df)
   col0  col1  col2  col3
0     0     1     2     3
1     4     5     6     7
2     8     9    10    11
3    12    13    14    15
    
s = df.stack().reset_index(drop=True)
print (s)
0      0
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
5      5
6      6
7      7
8      8
9      9
10    10
11    11
12    12
13    13
14    14
15    15
dtype: int32
```

Another idea with [`numpy.ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
s = pd.Series(df.to_numpy().ravel())
print (s)
0      0
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
5      5
6      6
7      7
8      8
9      9
10    10
11    11
12    12
13    13
14    14
15    15
dtype: int32
```